# issue regarding infinite scroll?

Tags: ajax, jsp, append, infinite-scroll

By using ajax call i want to append data to index.jsp  when scrollbar reaches document's end.

For that I am using two .jsp programs

1) To generating ajax call **index.jsp**

2)  **retrived data should append to index.jsp** by calling **data.jsp**

**index.jsp**

First it'l render 12 items.  when we scrolling to end, index.jsp calls data.jsp
 to append next 12 items.
 But here issue in this i am successfully getting alert message when scroller reaches end    but not next 12 items.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "data.jsp",
          data:data,
          success: function(data) {
                            alert('hai');  //to check ajax call only                
                            $("#bodycontent").append(data);
                            console.log(res);               
                                 }
   });
```

**data.jsp**

This data should append to index.jsp.

First I retrieved records into resultset " rs "

```
 while(rs.next())
{  %>
  <div class="pin" >

        <a href=<%out.print(rs.getString(2));%> target="_blank">
<img src="<%out.println(rs.getString(1));%>" onerror="imgError(this);" ></img></a>

        </div>
<%}
```

here,

**am i fallowing correct process or not?**

**can anybody suggest how can i append this data to index.jsp?**